# Global variable only for one user

Tags: python, django

I'm building a Django App and I need your help in order to manage sessions of my users.

For now, my index.html is my login page. It is a form (username,password).
When user clicks on login, i get the form, compare it to my users SQL Table, then if it matches, I render some global variables (firstname1,lastname1) to profil_page.html . Let's say i just login with (username1,password1).

When i try my app on another computer, with another login (username2,password2) , it takes me to profil_page.html and i can see (firstname2,lastname2) on my page.

The problem is, when i go back to my first computer which was logged in (username1,password1), i refresh the page and now i see (firstname2,lastname2) on the page.

I guess it is a problem of sessions. I want my global variable to be for one computer, not for my entire app.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Have you been reading this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/ ?

Comment: Don 't reinvent the wheel, Django has a stable, tested users/auth/session system, so just use it.

Comment: Oh and yes: I think you've understood why you shouldn't use globals in a long-running multithread / multiprocess app ? The same process will handle multiple requests, so each time a view that writes/mutates gobals is called, it will overwrite the previous values. It's even more funny when you have multiple concurrent processes and any user request can be served by any of the processes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a variable per-user, just create a session variable. That way it would remain the same unless the user session expires.

```
request.session['name'] = 'hello'
```

Comment: Yes, except session is not in capitals

Comment: @Daniel Thanks. Fixed it. It's been a while since I used them.